# Expected Value to grab a ball

Tags: probability

Say we have $b$ blue balls and $r$ red balls in a urn. Randomly we grab a ball out of the urn, until we grab a blue ball. Now I want to find the expected value of the number of balls that have been grabbed till the blue ball appears.

We can use this identity:
\begin{align}
E[X] = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} P(X>n).
\end{align}
And we can say that $P(X>k) = 1 - \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{k-1} P(X = j)$. Is this correct?

Finally, we want to find that the expected value is equal to $\frac{b+r+1}{b+1}$.

Comment: Are the balls replaced after grabbing them?

Comment: Fix a red ball and consider only this red ball and the b blue balls. By symmetry the probability that the red ball pops out before every blue ball is 1/(b+1). Adding this r times, the mean number of red balls popping out before the first blue ball is r/(b+1). And the mean number of balls grabbed when the first blue ball appears is 1 more, that is, 1+r/(b+1) = (b+1+r)/(b+1). No expectation there...

Comment: $P(X > k) = 1 - \sum_{j=0}^kP(X = j)$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the probability of taking a blue ball after you'd taken a red one changes, since you now have one less red ball (that is assuming you don't put the ball back to the urn).

Let $X$ be the number of taken red balls before a blue is shown (so the blue one is not counted).

$$P(X=n)=
\frac{r}{r+b}\times\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}\times...\times\frac{r-(n-1)}{r+b-(n-1)}\times\frac{b}{r+b-n}=\\
\frac{r!\times(r+b-n)!}{(r-n)!\times(r+b)!}\times\frac{b}{r+b-n}=
\frac{b\times r!}{(r+b)!}\times\frac{(r+b-n-1)!}{(r-n)!}\\
E[X]=
\sum_{n=0}^r nP(X=n)=
\frac{b\times r!}{(r+b)!}\times\sum_{n=0}^r n\frac{(r+b-n-1)!}{(r-n)!}
$$

For the sum I used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n*%28r%2Bb-n-1%29%21%2F%28%28r-n%29%21%29%2C%20n%3D0%20to%20r).

$$E[T]=
\frac{b\times r!}{(r+b)!}\times\frac{(b+r)!}{b\times(b+1)\times(r-1)!}\\
E[T]=\frac{r}{(b+1)}
$$

There was a lot of $b$, $r$, $n$ and factorials involved, so I hope I hadn't mess up, even though the final result seems pretty reasonable.